# How to rotate triangle in Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want the figure to rotate.

```
\begin{figure}
              \begin{tikzpicture}
                  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
                  \coordinate (B) at (1,-2);
                  \coordinate (C) at (3,2);
                  \draw[thin, dashed](A)node[left]{A}--(B)node[below]{B}--(C)node[above]{C}--cycle;
                  \draw[thick,rotate around={90:(B)}](A)node[left]{A}--(B)node[below]{B}--(C)node[above]{C}--cycle;
              \end{tikzpicture}
          \end{figure}
```

But, The figure doesn't rotate.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/681329/47927

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=30]
            \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
            \coordinate (B) at (1,-2);
            \coordinate (C) at (3,2);
            \draw[thin, dashed,](A)node[left]{A}--(B)node[below]{B}--(C)node[above]{C}--cycle;
            \draw[thick,rotate around={90:(B)}](A)node[left]{A}--(B)node[below]{B}--(C)node[above]{C}--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
```